# Is it possible to fetch mails from Gmails older than n days in Javascript/Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've managed to setup the oauth Login using [oauth API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html) in javascript/Chrome Extension and trying to fetch all the emails from Gmail using `https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/` but I get empty string back. But I do get gmail contacts using following code:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";
oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, onContacts, {
  'parameters' : {
    'alt' : 'json',
    'max-results' : 100
  }
});
```

Am I using the wrong URL to fetch emails? 
Is there any example available I can go through?